# Exporting Georeferenced PDFs using ArcGIS Desktop 9.3?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-9.3, geospatial-pdf

I am using ArcGIS Desktop 9.3 and I want to export maps in georeferenced PDFs.

Earlier I knew that there is an advanced option in file>export map>options>advanced where I was able able export map georeferencing information.

However, when I try to export following the above instructions I cannot find (export map georeference information) in advanced option.

What is the problem?

Comment: Sorry I have checked both data view and layout view. But found nothing.

Answer (score 3):

I just went to the Online Help where, at the end of the [Advanced PDF features](http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.3/index.cfm?TopicName=Advanced_PDF_features) page it says:

> Note: PDF Map Georeference export functionality is not present in the
>   initial ArcGIS 9.3 installation. It must be enabled via installation
>   of a free general patch on top of 9.3, available from
>   http://support.esri.com, entitled "ArcGIS (Desktop, Engine, Server)
>   9.3 map export patch to support Adobe Acrobat 9 PDF".
>
> The ArcGIS 9.3 Service Pack, once released, will also enable this
>   functionality.

Comment: @kamalsarkar If you have not done so yet I recommend taking the [Tour] which mentions that the best way to thank answerers is by clicking the green Accept button.